# Arduino push Button

Tags: arduino-uno

I need a help in arduino uno r3 with push button. By using the registers without using the pinMode, digitalWrite, digitalRead if-else, and switch-case.

```
int led1=2, led2=3, led3=4, led4=5;
int led5=8, led6=9, led7=10, led8=11;
int button=12;
int i,j,k;

void setup() {
    DDRB=DDRB|B00001111;
    DDRD=DDRD|B00111100;

    Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {
    int f=0;
    for(int s=0;s<16;s++){
        int k=0;
        int i=0b00001;
        int j=0b0011;
        PORTB=f;
        f +=1;
        if (f==64){f=0;}
        PORTD=0;
        for(k=0;k<7;k++){
            delay(250);
            PORTD=i;
            delay(250);
            PORTD=j;
            i=(i<<1);
            j=(j<<1);
        } 
        j=(j>>1);
        for(int d=0; d<9; d++){
            delay(250);
            PORTD=i;
            delay(250);
            PORTD=j;
            i=(i>>1);
            j=(j>>1);    
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code. That what I need is to make a while loop for the push button. When I will push the button the program will be start and when I push the button again program will stop.

Comment: What do you call for "program", a defined routine or do you want to turn on/off the Arduino?

Comment: a defined routine the led will turn on

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this in 2 way.

## First one

The simple one is writing and reading a byte directly into/fom eeprom. Everytime you press the push button, you need to read it first and validate this value. Lets supose your byte means 0 to turned off and 1 to turned on. So if you push the button and the already saved byte is 0, so you need to change this to 1.

You are going to write using this:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/EEPROMWrite

After this management, you will need to read this byte constantly inside your loop statement. If byte is 1, so your thread can be executed.

You are going to read using this: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/EEPROMRead

## Second

This is a cannon to kill a mosquito, but can be reused later to manage other kinds of informations. You are going to use the same logic, but saving more detailed or complex values. We are talking about some kind of database.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/DatabaseLibrary

I'm sorry but I can't write to you a sample code right now. Job first. If you can't do this untill the end of the day, maybe I can come later and comlete this post to help you out.

Comment: I didnt understand. A push buttonn dosen't hold an state, if he is pressed once, he just send a signal. You need to choose what are you going to do with this signal. https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/pushbutton